# How to schedule ClamAv to perform a daily scan

Tags: bash, 15.10, antivirus, clamav

I want to schedule a daily scan in my Home directory using ClamAv.
Can anybody explain me how to perform such task using a bash script?
I don't need to scan mails, just Home directory and maybe other directories.
Thank you

P.s.: I don't really need it, but is there a way to perform a scan on the whole pc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `cron` for this instead of strictly using `bash`. In the directory `/etc/cron.daily/` create a small script `clamavscan.sh` that looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
clamscan /home/username/
```

Then be sure to make the script executable with `chmod +x clamavscan.sh`.
This should run the clamscan of your home directory once daily at 6:25 (as you can see in the file `/etc/crontab`).

---

To have ClamAV scan you entire machine, you should just be able to run `clamscan /`, although this might require root privileges to really scan everything.

Comment: What will ClamAv do if it finds some threats?

Comment: I don't know what ClamAv's default behavior is. You could probably set ClamAv to automatically delete/quarantine/whatever the threats so you don't have to deal with them. Otherwise, if you want to make the call manually, you could make a slightly more sophisticated `clamavscan.sh` script that somehow alerts you to make a decision. At the very least you can redirect the output of the `clamscan` so you have a logfile to check for threats.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to create a similar cron job myself today.  I went a slightly different route. I opened up `/etc/crontab` and added the following job:

```
0 18 * * SUN root rm -rf /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
1 18 * * SUN root freshclam
22 18 * * SUN root clamscan -r -i / | grep FOUND >> /home/osamu/virus-scan-reports/virus-scan-report-`date +"\%d-\%m-\%Y"`.txt
```

If someone else has a better way to schedule regular virus scans including updating the known virus database please reply this thread.